# How to understand a type definition?

Tags: ocaml

> type 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;;

Is it a type definition, where `a` is a type parameter, and `tree` is the type name?

In `Node of`, is `Node` a built-in type of OCaml? What does `of` mean?

Thanks.

Comment: For completeness it's important imho to comment on the use of arrows `->` in datatypes/type definitions as well e.g. `type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit;;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `'a` is a type parameter and `tree` is a type name (these are usually called variants in OCaml). This is reversed order from most other languages. `Node` is a constructor (called tag in OCaml) and `of` is just a keyword in OCaml to specify the types of the constructor arguments. `Node` is not a built-in type of OCaml (it is not even a type, but rather, as a I said, a constructor).

Hence `Node (5, Empty, Node (6, Empty, Empty))` is something of type `int tree` (something like `Tree<Int>` in Java).

It may make more sense if you start with a simpler variant.

```
type shape = Square of int | Rectangle of int * int
```

`Shape` and `Rectangle` are tags (again constructors) that I have just made up that allow me to construct values of type `shape` (in this case I've chosen to have `Shape` take only one argument because only length is needed to specify a square, whereas `Rectangle`s need both length and width). Nothing ever has a type of `Shape` or `Rectangle`, but things can have a type of `shape`.

One way to read that line in English is "I have defined a type called `shape`. A `shape` is either a `Square` of a single integer, or a `Rectangle` of two integers."

Now maybe for some reason I also want to label my shapes.

```
type 'label labelledshape = LabelledSquare of 'label * int | LabelledRectangle of 'label * int * int
```

The quote `'` distinguishes that `label` is not a type (such as `int`), but is rather a variable. This allows me to write something like `LabelledSquare ("a label for a square", 5)` which is of type `string labelledshape`

Note that although this allows for polymorphism, these are not what is known as "polymorphic variants" in OCaml. I will not talk about that here, rather I'll just recommend either looking at OCaml documentation or browsing Stack Overflow for more details on that.

Comment: Thanks. Is `Node` a type constructor, i.e. a constructor which construct a type? Does `Node` ever need to be defined?

Comment: @Tim yes it is a type constructor and therefore no it does not need to have an implementation defined

Comment: Why is there no need to define `Node`? If `Node` is not defined, is `'a tree`  an undefined type?

Comment: `'a tree` is defined. Let me rephrase what I mean by no implementation is defined. In a lot of ML-inspired languages you make up the values of a type "from thin air" so to speak. For example you might ask for a variant `type color = Red | Green | Blue` "What is Red really? Where is its implementation defined?" And I would reply you've defined a new primitive, Red that is not composed of anything else and is of type `color`. It would equivalent to trying to answer those questions for something like the integer 5. A similar idea holds for `Node`, it's just that it takes arguments.

Comment: This is different from languages such as C++ or Java where you rarely define new primitive values of a type, but rather construct classes that are composites of other types. That being said you can emulate this with enumerations, but people often attach a different intuition to that

Comment: I am seeing the arrows used in an actual type definition e.g. `open Format;;
type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit;;`. In this context what does the arrow mean? I am usually used seeing data types defined using constructors. Without this I feel confused. Can you comment (or expand your answer) to mention how arrows are used in type definitions? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of type definitions:

### Definition of a new sum type

From that type definition:

```
type 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;;
```

Here are roughly the "facts" that the OCaml compiler knows about based on it:

- `tree` is a unary type constructor. That means that for any type `t`, `t tree` is a type as well (example: `int tree`).
- `Empty` is a 0-ary constructor for `'a tree`. That means that `Empty` has type `t tree` for any `t`.
- `Node` is a 3-ary constructor. Here this means that if `a` has type `t`, `b` has type `t tree`, and `c has type` t tree`, then` Node (a, b, c)`has type`t tree`(note: that's the same`t`)
- those are the only two ways to have a value of type `t tree`. That means that you can use pattern matching (`match ... with | Empty -> ... | Node (a, b, c) -> ...`).

### Definition of a type alias

A definition can also be something that looks like:

```ml
type t = existing_type
```

In that case, `t` is just a new neame for the `existing_type`.

For example:

```ml
type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit
```

This means that something that is a `int pp` has type `Format.formatter -> int -> unit`.

This is the type of a function that takes a formatter and an integer and returns `unit`. Such as :

```ml
type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit

module M : sig
  val pp_int : int pp
end = struct
  let pp_int fmt n = Format.fprintf fmt "%d" n
end
```

Comment: I am seeing the arrows used in an actual type definition e.g. `open Format;;
type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit;;`. In this context what does the arrow mean? I am usually used seeing data types defined using constructors. Without this I feel confused. Can you comment (or expand your answer) to mention how arrows are used in type definitions? thanks!

Comment: @CharlieParker it's an alias to an arrow type, the type of functions. I expanded the answer with this.

Comment: I think what confuses me the most is that to create values for I type I thought we needed their constructors. So does pp not have constructors? or is pp the constructor? Usually I am used to pp "pointing" to the valid way to construct values of that type but here we don't need that? I'm confused how to create values basically with that syntax.

Comment: in the case of a type alias, there's no extra constructor - the definition of `pp` is just a shorter name for the expanded alias `Format.formatter -> `a -> unit`. 2 other examples if that's the arrow part that's confusing:
- `type integer = int` just creates a new name for `int`. `5 : integer` is valid
- `type 'a pair = 'a * 'a` means that you can use `(5, 3) : int pair`

Comment: The relevant part of the manual is https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/typedecl.html , look for "Type abbreviation" (it mentions a "type constructor", this is `pp`, `integer`, and `pair` in my examples - not a data constructor like `Empty`)